# Surround date with single quote in dynamic SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, concatenation

I am having this piece of code in an oracle package,

```
 PROCEDURE GET_LOGIN
    (
           PIN_FROM_DATE             IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
          ,PIN_TO_DATE               IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
          ,CV_1                      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) 
    AS      
          LV_SQL long ;     
          LV_SQL_DATE long ;     
    BEGIN

    LV_SQL_DATE:='';

    IF (PIN_FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL AND PIN_TO_DATE IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 

    LV_SQL_DATE := ' WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN '||   TO_DATE(PIN_FROM_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')   ||' AND '|| TO_DATE(PIN_TO_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ||' '; 

    END IF;

    LV_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM LOGIN_DATA '||LV_SQL_DATE;
    OPEN CV_1 FOR LV_SQL;

    END GET_LOGIN;
```

I am passing the from date and to date to this `PROCEDURE` and running a query with between clause.

The default date format is this 
`select sysdate from dual;` 14-FEB-18

```
LV_SQL_DATE := ' WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN '||   TO_DATE(PIN_FROM_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')   ||' AND '|| TO_DATE(PIN_TO_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ||' ';
```

above query concatenates the converted date with sql string.

which will be like

```
WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN 14-FEB-18 AND 14-FEB-18 ;
```

which will throw and error, because its expects like this

```
WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN '14-FEB-18' AND '14-FEB-18' ;
```

How do i concatenate the date conversion with single quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Quite simple.

you have this code :

```
LV_SQL_DATE := ' WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN '||   TO_DATE(PIN_FROM_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')   ||' AND '|| TO_DATE(PIN_TO_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ||' ';
```

Change it to:

```
LV_SQL_DATE := ' WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN '''||   TO_DATE(PIN_FROM_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')   ||''' AND '''|| TO_DATE(PIN_TO_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ||''' ';
```

Difference is : use **'''** instead of **'** before appending the dates

This just answers your question of concatenating.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf : Why do you think do you need  `TO_DATE ()` for  `PIN_TO_DATE` and `PIN_FROM_DATE` when they are already  `DATE` variables?

Comment: I did not use it. came from @Yoosuf. I just facilitated the appending of single quote. I have not changed the code logic.

Answer (score 1):

The variables  `PIN_FROM_DATE,PIN_TO_DATE`  are already of type  `date` - so there is no need to convert them to date again.

I think that you could use something like this:

```
LV_SQL_DATE := 'WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE) BETWEEN :my_PIN_FROM_DATE and :my_PIN_TO_DATE' ;
```

And then

```
OPEN CV_1 FOR LV_SQL using PIN_FROM_DATE,PIN_TO_DATE;
```

Comment: yes this is one way of doing it, notice that the variables can be null,in that case when this `OPEN CV_1 FOR LV_SQL using PIN_FROM_DATE,PIN_TO_DATE;` runs , it might throw `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist`

Comment: You are already checking for `nulls`. So it is just a matter of adjusting your code a little bit more and executing the above `open` only  when bind variables are not `null` - otherwise use another `open`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't need dynamic SQL here. your  final `CURSOR` is equivalent to.

```
OPEN CV_1 FOR SELECT *
FROM   login_data
WHERE  ( CASE
           WHEN pin_from_date IS NOT NULL
                AND pin_to_date IS NOT NULL THEN
             CASE
               WHEN TRUNC (login_date) BETWEEN pin_from_date AND pin_from_date
             THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END
           ELSE 1
         END ) = 1
```

Comment: yes, this is one way of doing it, but i have many more queries which gets attached to this.